# Spark streaming StreamingContext.start() - Error starting receiver 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a project that's using spark streaming and I'm running it with 'spark-submit' but I'm hitting this error:

```
15/01/14 10:34:18 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.log(KafkaInputDStream.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.logInfo(KafkaInputDStream.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the code that the error is coming from, everything runs fine up until ssc.start()

```
    val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Jumbly_StreamingConsumer")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
    .
    .
    .
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I've run the SparkPi example using 'spark-submit' and it runs fine so I can't seem to figure out what's causing the problem on my application, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: sounds like a version issue. Check the Spark version in your cluster  vs the one in your dependencies.

Comment: Everything seems to be in order, Spark version is 1.1.0 and the dependencies for spark-core, spark-streaming & spark-streaming-kafka are all 1.1.0

Comment: WHat's in the . . . part? SInce you say it's the ssc.start() that fails it seems relevant to know what's between checkpoint and that!

Comment: You may have found it already but someone else has had a similar issue: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201409.mbox/%3CCADPi3fgPiwXc0WLKGU6Pvbs-D0LK4Mzs_hhSP2DctM2A5UOEZw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: @Paul and more importantly... the conclusion there was "Yeah, I forgot to build the new jar file for spark 1.1...
And now the errors are gone."  - this is a version conflict issue from a mile away

Comment: It is a version issue like @maasg said, the problem was that I hadn't updated my build.sbt file to reflect the fact that I am now using newer versions of spark-core, spark-streaming & spark-streaming-kafka. Updated the file and ran >sbt assembly, now it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobertNolan great. I've added that as an answer for the reference of future visitors.

Comment: @maasg I've accepted it, thanks again for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `java.lang.AbstractMethod`:

> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only
>   occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly
>   changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

This means that there's a version incompatibility between the compile and runtime dependencies. Make sure you align those versions to solve this issue.

Comment: i.e., check your pom.xml or build.sbt and make sure the MLLib version matches your Spark version.